# Not able to access a controller which uses authentication with React frontend ASP.NET Core 7 Web API backend (but able to do it with postman)

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0

I am trying to create a simple ASP.NET Core 7 Web API where a user can log in and add words to his list to study and see those words.

Here you can see my `AccountCcontroller` and `WordsController`:

```
using LanguageLearningApp.Data;
using LanguageLearningApp.DTOs;
using LanguageLearningApp.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace LanguageLearningApp.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    //[Authorize] // If I uncomment then I will get 404 not found, I tried this to debug
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class WordsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        public WordsController(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _context = context;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetWords()
        {
            // Get the current user's ID
            var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

            // Check if user is authenticated
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }

            // Retrieve the words specific to the authenticated user
            var userWords = _context.Words.Where(w => w.UserId == userId).ToList();

            return Ok(userWords);
        }

        [HttpPost("addWord")]
        public IActionResult AddWord(WordDTO wordDto)
        {
            // Get the current user's ID
            var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

            // Check if user is authenticated
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }

            // Create a new Word object
            var word = new Word
            {
                LanguageFrom = wordDto.LanguageFrom,
                LanguageTo = wordDto.LanguageTo,
                UserId = userId
            };

            // Add the word to the context and save changes
            _context.Words.Add(word);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return Ok(word);
        }

        [HttpPost("addWords")]
        public IActionResult AddWords(IEnumerable<WordDTO> wordDtos)
        {
            // Get the current user's ID
            var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

            // Check if user is authenticated
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }

            // Create a list to store the new Word objects
            List<Word> words = new List<Word>();

            foreach (var wordDto in wordDtos)
            {
                // Create a new Word object for each WordDTO
                var word = new Word
                {
                    LanguageFrom = wordDto.LanguageFrom,
                    LanguageTo = wordDto.LanguageTo,
                    UserId = userId
                };
                words.Add(word);
            }

            // Add the words to the context and save changes
            _context.Words.AddRange(words);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return Ok(words);
        }
    }
}
```

```
using LanguageLearningApp.DTOs;
using LanguageLearningApp.Helpers;
using LanguageLearningApp.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace LanguageLearningApp.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class AccountController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly ILogger<AccountController> _logger;

        public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<AccountController> logger)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _configuration = configuration;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterRequestDTO model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Username, Email = model.Email };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User registered successfully.");

                    // Generate email confirmation token
                    var token = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);

                    // Generate confirmation link
                    var confirmationLink = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, token }, Request.Scheme);

                    // Send confirmation email
                    //await EmailSender.SendEmailAsync(user.Email, "Confirm Your Email",
                    //    $"Please confirm your email by clicking the link: <a href=\"{confirmationLink}\">Confirm Email</a>");

                    return Ok("Registration successful. Please check your email to confirm your account.");
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest(result.Errors);
                }
            }

            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginRequestDTO model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in successfully.");

                    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
                    var token = JwtHelper.GenerateJwtToken(user.Id, user.UserName, _configuration);

                    return Ok(new { Token = token });
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest("Invalid login attempt.");
                }
            }

            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet("ConfirmEmail")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string token)
        {
            if (userId == null || token == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Invalid email confirmation token.");
            }

            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound($"User not found with ID '{userId}'.");
            }

            var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, token);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return Ok("Email confirmed successfully. You can now log in.");
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest("Email confirmation failed.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `program.cs`:

```
using LanguageLearningApp.Data;
using LanguageLearningApp.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


// Authentication
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Jwt:Issuer").Value,
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Jwt:Audience").Value,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Jwt:SecretKey").Value))
        };
    });

// Authorization
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

// Add CORS policy
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowReactApp",
        builder => builder
        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials()
        .WithExposedHeaders("Authorization") // <-- Add this line to expose the "Authorization" header
    );
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("AllowReactApp"); // Use the CORS policy
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

React function where the API is called:

```
export async function fetchWords() {
    try {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        console.log(token);
        const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/api/words`, {
            headers: {
                "access-control-allow-origin" : "*", 
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
            }
        });
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);  // Log the entire error object
        throw new Error(error.response?.data?.message || 'Fetching words failed');
    }
}
```

Jwthelper.cs:

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;

namespace LanguageLearningApp.Helpers
{
    public static class JwtHelper
    {
        public static string GenerateJwtToken(string userId, string username, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(configuration["Jwt:SecretKey"]);

            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userId),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username),
                }),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(double.Parse(configuration["Jwt:AccessTokenExpirationMinutes"])),
                Issuer = configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                Audience = configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };
            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried copying the token from the console log in browser when trying to call the API with react and then paste it in postman, but somehow that doesn't work either, so it seems the token is the issue, but debugging everything looks exactly the same (if I do with postman or with react app; the jwt token is generated with the same input parameters) even in jwt.io everything is the same and looking correct, so I don't get what is wrong with the token, or maybe it is something in the way react calls my API, but normal controllers which doesn't require authentication do work, so I am confused here.

Comment: You said you could do it with postman in title ,but you mentioned  "trying to call the API with react and then paste it in postman, but somehow that doesn't work eithe" so could it work?

Comment: Yes with postman I mean postman only so doing the login obtaining the token and using that token to obtain the words. However if I login with react and log the token or take it from the request header and use that token then in postman it doesn’t work and i get 404 not found (if authorize attribute is there) or 401 not authorized (because userId will be null in the code when debugging words controller). One more thing both cases when I use jwt.io I see the contents of the token they are exactly the same

Comment: The 404 error seems caused by Identity accroding to your description,have you tried to specific the AuthScheme with [Authorize("Bearer")]?

Comment: I tried the following adding [Authorize("Bearer")] then I get 500 error saying bearer authentization policy named '"Bearer" was not found then I tried doing [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] then i get 401 error,  but looking at response header i see www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid token" -> something is going wrong with the token it seems, but using jwt io I cant tell because all the values look good

Comment: see my blog post here for ideas https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Thanks, but cant get it to work

Comment: have you checked the detailed message as the blog?

Comment: I added it to the options, but I dont see it unfortunately. I do see in the debugging though with using the logging statements this: my jwt token and then: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Debug: AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was not authenticated. So it seems as it using cookie based middleware instead of jwt

Comment: I solved it problem was that identity causes to use cookie based authentication

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it, the problem was that identity used cookie based authetication, this is the updated program.cs:

```html
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

// Authentication
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Jwt:Issuer").Value,
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Jwt:Audience").Value,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Jwt:SecretKey").Value))
        };
    });

// Authorization
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

// Add CORS policy
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowReactApp",
        builder => builder
        .WithOrigins("https://localhost:3000")
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .WithHeaders("Authorization", "Content-Type", "access-control-allow-origin")
        .AllowCredentials()
        .WithExposedHeaders("Authorization")
    );
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("AllowReactApp"); // Use the CORS policy
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```